# How to refer to unnamed destructured parameters in ES6?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In the code below, I'm wondering if there is something to replace **magic** that will do the same thing as the call to foo just above it.

```
function foo(a, { b=0, c=1 } = {} ) {
    console.log(a, b, c);
}
function bar({ b=2, c=3 } = {} ) {
    foo(99, { b:b, c:c });
//  foo(99, magic); // should be equivalent to the above call
}
bar({c:4});
```

Reason being I have a function where the unnamed object parameter is quite large and it seems like a shorthand would look nicer and be less error prone than writing all the object keys each time. (I'm porting a library from python to ES6 and trying to maintain the existing api as much possible. )

---

Edit: Another way to ask this is: "Is there a way to loop through these parameters **b** and **c** without knowing their names?"

---

Edit2: Here's the real code looks like. Functional but ugly. Must be a better way.

```
function Decoder({
    encoding="utf-8",
    object_hook=echo,
    parse_float=Number,
    parse_int=Number,
    parse_constant=Number,
    strict=true,
    object_pairs_hook=echo} = {}) {

    if(!(this instanceof Decoder)) {
        return new Decoder({
            encoding:encoding,
            object_hook:object_hook,
            parse_float:parse_float,
            parse_int:parse_int,
            parse_constant:parse_constant,
            strict:strict,
            object_pairs_hook:object_pairs_hook});
    }
    this.encoding = encoding;
    this.object_hook = object_hook;
    this.parse_float = parse_float;
    this.parse_int = parse_int;
    this.parse_constant = parse_constant;
    this.strict = strict;
    this.object_pairs_hook = object_pairs_hook;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perform the destructure inside the function. Something like this:

```
function bar(obj) {
  const { b = 2, c = 3 } = obj
  const magic = { b, c }
  foo(99, magic); // abracadabra
}
```